# How to switch between a production and development database configuration in Play?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure multiple databases work in Play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391987/how-do-i-configure-multiple-databases-work-in-play-2-0)

Basically, I have an app which I'm testing locally, and then deploying to the server. I'd like a painless way of either automatically, or manually selecting which database configuration to use. How can this be done in Play framework? I've seem some info of this in the documention but I don't know Scala, therefore I'd like some simple instructions if possible.

Comment: are you using Play 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Alternative configuration file on localhost where you can override DB settings (and other elements) as described in [this documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionConfiguration). In this case in `application.conf` put data of the production server and in `local_something.conf` put local data.

Also You can put directly overrided value in the command line ie as `-Ddb.default.driver=some.driver` anyway it will be just less comfortable than using the file.