# How to keep separate dev, test, and prod databases in Play! 2 Framework?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework

In particular, for test-cases, I want to keep the test database separate so that the test cases don't interfere with development or production databases.

What are some good practices for separating development, test and production environments?

**EDIT1: Some context**

In Ruby On Rails, there are different configuration files by convention for different environments. So does Play! 2 also support that ?

Or, do I have to cook the configuration files, and then write some glue code that selects the appropriate configuration files ?

At the moment if I run `sbt test` it uses development database ( configured as "default" in conf/application.conf ). However I would like Play!2 to use a different test database.

**EDIT2: On commands that play provides**

For Play! 2 framework, I observed this.

```
$ help play
Welcome to Play 2.2.2!

These commands are available:
-----------------------------
...OUTPUT SKIPPED...
run <port>                 Run the current application in DEV mode.
test                       Run Junit tests and/or Specs from the command line
start <port>               Start the current application in another JVM in PROD mode.
...OUTPUT SKIPPED...
```

There are three well defined commands for "test", "development" and "production" instances which are:

- `test`: This runs the test cases. So it should automatically select `test` configuration.
- `run <port>`: this runs the `development` instance on the specified `port`. So this command should automatically select `development` configuration.
- `start <port>`: this runs the `production` instance on the specified `port`. So this should automatically select `production` configuration.

However, all these commands select the values that are provided in `conf/application.conf`. I feel there is some gap to be filled here.

Please do correct me if I am wrong.

**EDIT3: Best approach is using Global.scala**

Described here: [How to manage application.conf in several environments with play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723224/how-to-manage-application-conf-in-several-environments-with-play-2-0)

Comment: Different configuration files? Your question is a bit too generic.

Comment: I just updated the question with "Some context".

Comment: While your edits have helped clarify what you're looking for this question is now looking much more like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391987/how-to-set-up-different-databases-per-environment-in-play-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice is keeping separate instances of the application in separate folders and synching them i.e. via git repo.

When you want to keep single instance you can use [**alternative configuration file**](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration) for each environment.

Comment: I think the "alternative configuration file" approach seems good. However, ideally I would like that "sbt test" automatically selects the "test" configuration.

Comment: Usually I'm just creating shell scripts for that like `dev.sh`, `prod.sh` etc. Additionally using i.e. Idea with Play support you can just create separate running configs

Comment: I found this approach most appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15937831/1119997

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.conf` file there is an entry (or entries) for your database, e.g. `db.default.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/devdb`

The conf file can read environment variables using `${?ENV_VAR_NAME}` syntax, so change that to something like `db.default.url=${?DB_URL}` and use environment variables.

Comment: Play supports overriding only selected configs in additional config files, it's documented officially

Comment: @biesior sorry, I'm confused by your comment as my answer didn't mention anything about additional config files

Comment: Just wanna say that's not necessary to set env vars - additional config files are more comfortable especially, when you have more configs depending on choosen environment

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to get this done and manage your configuration easier is via GlobalSettings. There is a method you can override and that its name is "onLoadConfig". Try check its api at [API_LINK](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/GlobalSettings.html#onLoadConfig(play.Configuration,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.ClassLoader))

Basically on your conf/ project folder, you'll setup similar to below:

```
conf/application.conf --> configurations common for all environment
conf/dev/application.conf --> configurations for development environment
conf/test/application.conf --> configurations for testing environment
conf/prod/application.conf --> configurations for production environment
```

So with this, your application knows which configuration to run for your specific environment mode. For a code snippet of my implementation on onLoadConfig try check my article at my [blog post](http://bit.ly/1AiZvX5)

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain why this is a bad approach.